# Activate USB Ports on CM4

Tags: usb

I have flashed to the emmc of my Raspy Pi CM4 the Rasp.-OS, it boots up
and I can see the desktop image. By default the USB Ports seem to be disabled (Energy saving, not good decision IMO)
and ssh is as I know also disabled by default.

And: The Pi is not displayed as a external drive if I set the jumper to "disable emmc boot" and plug it via usb cable to my laptop...

What can I do to get the USB Ports activated?

I have found some tutorials about it but it didnt helped me further..

Comment: useful information would be what carrier board are you using

Answer (score 0):

Add `dtoverlay=dwc2,dr_mode=host` to your `config.txt`